# What track Google Play Developer API will be used by default?

Tags: google-play

I use [Edits.insert](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/insert) to create an "edit", and after that I change some listings. What version of the app or what track will be updated? 
Documentation tells the `Edits.insert`...

> Creates a new edit for an app, populated with the app's current state.

But what is "current state"? I have current production version, rollout production and a few alphas (one of them is newer than rollout production).

Or listings doesn't have versioning at all and are common for all apks and traks?

Answer (score 0):

Listings are common for all APKs and tracks.